# How to send trigger onClick to child component in soldjs and display it in parent?

Tags: solid-js

I was trying to take example from react but seem it doesn't work as I expected.
I am trying to open a modal when user click the button in parent component, but function to open modal is located in the child component.

Parent component just where i try to invoke a modal:

```
   <label class="text-white m-5 p-1">
    <input type="checkbox" checked={false} onChange={handleCheck} />
    &nbsp;I have read and agree to the <button onClick={}>Privacy</button>
    <Portal>
      <TermsModal />
    </Portal>
  </label>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the Modal component to control the state, instead of it being passed with props you can use this pattern:

```js
const { Modal, openModal } = createModal();

return (
  <>
    <button type="button" onClick={openModal}>
      open modal
    </button>
    <Modal />
  </>
);
```

It may be weird at first, but it's really fun and powerful :)

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/d3a74069-e3d4-4d3e-9fb2-bafc5d6f5bf5

Comment: Thank you it helped! I just have some small issue now because of the require annotation in input which popping up but its something for another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Create a signal inside parent component and pass it to the child component. Bind the visibility of the modal window to the signal's value:

```js
import { Component, createSignal, Show } from 'solid-js';
import { Portal, render } from 'solid-js/web';

const Modal: Component<{ show: boolean }> = (props) => {
  return (
    <Show when={props.show}>
      <div>Modal Window</div>
    </Show>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = createSignal(false);

  const toggleShow = () => setShow(prev => !prev);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Show: {show() ? 'true': 'false'} <button onClick={toggleShow}>Toggle Show</button></div>
      <Portal><Modal show={show()} /></Portal>
    </div>
  )
};

render(() => <App />, document.body);
```

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/adf9ba7a-3e1b-4ce9-92b2-e78ff3fa55ec

You can further improve your component by creating a close handler and passing it to the child component. Now, modal window can show a close button.

Also you can add an event handler to the document in order to close the window whenever `Escape` key is pressed:

```js
import { Component, createSignal, onCleanup, onMount, Show } from 'solid-js';
import { Portal, render } from 'solid-js/web';

const Modal: Component<{ show: boolean, close: () => void }> = (props) => {
  const handleKeydown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      props.close();
    }
  };

  onMount(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
  });

  onCleanup(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown);
  });

  return (
    <Show when={props.show}>
      <div>Modal Window  <button onclick={props.close}>close</button></div>
    </Show>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = createSignal(false);
  const close = () => setShow(false);

  const toggleShow = () => setShow(prev => !prev);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Show: {show()} <button onClick={toggleShow}>Toggle Show</button></div>
      <Portal><Modal show={show()} close={close} /></Portal>
    </div>
  )
};

render(() => <App />, document.body);
```

https://playground.solidjs.com/anonymous/0ae98cf1-19d6-487f-80dc-72d3c2e554dc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state in the parent component to keep track of whether the modal should be open or closed, and pass a function as a prop to the child component that updates that state:

```
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleButtonClick = () => {
  setIsModalOpen(true);
};

return (
  <div>
    <label className="text-white m-5 p-1">
      <input type="checkbox" checked={false} onChange={handleCheck} />
      &nbsp;I have read and agree to the <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Privacy</button>
      <Portal>
        <TermsModal isOpen={isModalOpen} onClose={() => setIsModalOpen(false)} />
      </Portal>
    </label>
  </div>
);

// Child component

const TermsModal = ({ isOpen, onClose }) => {
  if (!isOpen) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      {/* Modal content */}
      <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```